# Make text on pdf file fit the placeholder on the paper when printing

Tags: html, css, odoo, qweb

I have a paper doc [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) i need to make a blank pdf file containing only the data of the place holder so that i put the paper on the printer and when i print my generated pdf report the data will fit exactly the paper, i can just make it from scratch the paper template and the data and print everything at once from the pdf file but i am not allowed to do it (long story) i just need a good approche i absolutely have no idea how to do it, my intial idea is to use html css since i am generating this pdf report from odoo's q-web repor

i have tried to make everything to pdf it worked but now its requested to get only the data on the pdf file without the page layout

Comment: @KJ the problem here is that I can't use just MS Word to create a doc file and then print it, I need to use odoo framework to create a blanc pdf file containing only the info needed to be printed on this paper and then print it, I just don't know a good way to put each information in it exact location so when printed on the paper the result would be just as if I made everything on my own (in short the question is not how I make a pdf file on odoo the problem here is just how I can guess the exact location of each info) sorry for my bad English

Comment: @KJ ok now i get it, its a good approach tnx

Answer (score 2):

I just did it by adding a background image in the qweb report using this property `t-attf-style="background-image:url()"` and placed the info in their respective text holder, after that, I just removed the background image and got my result